# How can i upload to cloudinary using signed signature

Tags: jquery, node.js, cloudinary

I need to secure client side upload to cloudinary,
So that I generated a signature token from my node server side using cloudinary api_secret key and time, 
used this code 
`api_sign_request = function(params_to_sign, api_secret)`. After these how to upload the image to cloudinary from front end side using this token

Comment: Firstly upload it to your server and then from your server upload it to cloudinary server.

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal Now I am using this method only, I need to change this to client side for better performance

Comment: If you want to shift to client side then it's not a good design, because then the unauthenticated user can also use that and can upload to your cloudinary server. Cloudnary does give [jquery sdk](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration) and [javascript sdk](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/javascript_integration) for integration and you don't need nodejs for that. But again as I said it is not good design. If you really want to go with client side then I sugest you to use [upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget)

Answer (score 7):

Let's all take a moment to point out how horrible Cloudinary's documentation is. It's easily the worst i've ever seen. Nightmare fuel.

Now that i've got that off my chest... I really needed to be able to do this and I spent way too long banging my head against walls for what should be extremely simple. Here it is...

#### Server (Node.js)

You'll need an endpoint that returns a signature-timestamp pair to the frontend:

```js
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary'

export async function createImageUpload() {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
  const signature = await cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request(
    {
      timestamp,
    },
    process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
  )
  return { timestamp, signature }
}
```

#### Client (Browser)

The client makes a request to the server for a signature-timestamp pair and then uses that to upload a file. The file used in the example should come from an `<input type='file'/>` change event etc.

```js
const CLOUD_NAME = process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME
const API_KEY = process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY

async function uploadImage(file) {
  const { signature, timestamp } = await api.post('/image-upload')
  const form = new FormData()
  form.append('file', file)
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload?api_key=${API_KEY}&timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature}`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form,
    }
  )
  const data = await res.json()
  return data.secure_url
}
```

That's it. That's all it takes. If only Cloudinary had this in their docs.

Many thanks to @jpschroeder's answer, which pointed me in the right direction from the start.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work with axios, and with fetch it works flawlessly.. Thanks tho, this is definitely the simplest way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is currently (Jan, 2020) no documented way to generate secure signed URLs for uploading files [like you would with S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). That's not to say it can't be done because the documentation hints that there is a way to do it, but I can't seem to find where to explains it.

This means you can only use Cloudinary’s "unsigned" uploads API, which seems borderline abandoned at this point since *the only front end upload SDK they have is only for jQuery*. Yeah...jQuery – if you've never heard of it don't be embarrassed, us old timers used to use it back in the old days while we listened to nirvana on cassette tape.

They do have [1 broken example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK) of doing an unsigned upload from the browser via vanilla JS. My personal axios/ES2015 example is this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const cloudName = 'foofoo'
const unsignedUploadPrefix = 'foobar'
const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const data = new FormData()  
  const file = e.target.files[0]
  data.append('upload_preset', unsignedUploadPrefix)
  data.append('file', file)
  axios.post(url, data)
})
```

Comment: I don't understand why they don't have a flow that is exactly the same as the code posted in this answer - but for signed uploads - eg an endpoint requiring a token. Nobody wants to install their janky ass humongous library

Answer (score -1):

Using our [upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) is a good way to go if you want to have client-side uploading.

What you could also try is to have [unsigned uploads](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_and_video_upload#unsigned_upload) using the browser, which we also support.

Although they are less secure than signed uploads, they require to configure an [upload preset](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_and_video_upload#upload_presets) which can be done only from your end and can be changed immediately to prevent abuse.